# Python regex for items in a list

Tags: python, regex, list, python-3.8

I have a list `cols` as following:

```
['Wed Estimate 6/10', 'Thu Estimate 6/11', 'Fri Estimate 6/12', 'Next Estimate 6/15-6/19']
```

When I try the following:

```
re.findall(r'\s\d/\d\w-\d/\d\w', cols[3])
```

I get `[' 6/15-6/19']` but when I try

```
[re.findall(r'\s\d/\d\w|\s\d/\d\w-\d/\d\w', x) for x in cols]
```

I get `[[' 6/10'], [' 6/11'], [' 6/12'], [' 6/15']]`

I want to achieve the following:

`[[' 6/10'], [' 6/11'], [' 6/12'], [' 6/15-6/19']]`

I am not sure why regex is behaving as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
import re
lst = ['Wed Estimate 6/10', 'Thu Estimate 6/11', 'Fri Estimate 6/12', 'Next Estimate 6/15-6/19']
lst_new = [re.findall(r'\d+\/\d+(?:-\d+\/\d+)?', x) for x in lst]
print(lst_new)
```

Returns:

```
[['6/10'], ['6/11'], ['6/12'], ['6/15-6/19']]
```

The pattern isn't too difficult but instead of alternation I used an optional non-capture group to be used on `##/##-##/##` patterns. I believe this would yield results faster.

The above would exclude the leading spaces. Not sure if that was a specific requirement. Also, if you want to limit the amount of digits in the `##/##` pattern to a max of two, maybe use `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?:-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})?` instead.

Another note; if the strings won't get more complicated than this sample data you could also just split your strings instead. For example:

```
lst_new = [[x.rpartition(' ')[2]] for x in lst]
```

Or:

```
lst_new = [[x.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]] for x in lst]
```